# Coredata Lightweight migration lost data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am not expert in coredata :(,

Steps I followed

1. Created New Modal Version (Editor --> Add New Modal version)
2. Select Current Modal version (Green check mark shows on newly added modal)
3. Added New Attribute of String type , With optional type
4. In AppDelegate  added following code for `NSPersistentContainer`

   ```
   let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
   description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
   description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
   container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
   ```

   My old modal version has many records and I am expecting to see all the records with new modal too but when I just run the application I am seeing that all data is lost like empty model.

Is it default behaviour of light weight migration ? or Am I missing something

Please guide

Comment: `NSPersistentContainer` enables Lightweight Migration by default. The extra code is redundant. And the migration doesn't delete anything. If the migration is not possible you get an error.

Comment: @vadian Yes , After comment that extra code you have suggested all data is back.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Make sure you are performing Light weight migration only. You can refer this tutorial. https://www.raywenderlich.com/7585-lightweight-migrations-in-core-data-tutorial#toc-anchor-010 Check "Inferred mapping models" section

Comment: @PavanKotesh  Vadian's comment fixes the issue, I have removed `NSPersistentStoreDescription` and all data is back, Anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSPersistentContainer` enables Lightweight Migration by default. **Delete the extra code**.

And the migration doesn't delete any data. If the migration is not possible you get an error.